# Create Angular form duplicate - Array of Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formbuilder, formarray

I'm making a wizard in order to fill in the info of a dog. I'm using reactive forms. The dog has properties such as a name which is a basic input, some are checkboxes, some are arrays, of allergies for example.
The problem is I want to be able to ask him initially about the number of dogs he has, and based on that for example if he said 2; every question asked will be shown twice and I'd be filling in the info for 2 objects.
A very similar example of what I'm trying to achieve is here: https://butternutbox.com/wizard/new upon clicking on the "I have another dog" button.
Here's a snippet of the code and you can find the full thing working in the following stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xndqqj?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html
**Html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <app-card cardTitle="Signup Wizard" [options]="false">
            <form [formGroup]="addCusForm">
                <aw-wizard #wizard class="arc-wizard">
                    <!-- NAME -->
                    <aw-wizard-step stepTitle="1">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h5>What's your dog's name?</h5>
                                <hr>
                                <h6>My dog is called</h6>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Dog's name"
                                        formControlName="DOG_NAME">
                                </div>                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 centered-content">
                                <div class="btn-group mt-10">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" awNextStep>Continue</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </aw-wizard-step>                   
                    
                    <!-- ALLERGIES -->
                    <aw-wizard-step stepTitle="10">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12" formArrayName="ALLERGIES_ARRAY">
                                <h5>Does {{addCusForm.get('DOG_NAME').value}} have any allergies?</h5>
                                <hr>
                                <h6>{{addCusForm.get('DOG_NAME').value}} is allergic to...</h6>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" (change)="unCheckAll()"
                                        [checked]="nthchecked">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label">Nothing</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"
                                    *ngFor="let allergy of addCusForm.get('ALLERGIES_ARRAY')['controls']; let i=index"
                                    [formGroupName]="i">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" formControlName="IS_SELECTED"
                                        (change)="onAllergyChange($event)">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label">{{allergy.get('ALLERGY_NAME').value}}</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 centered-content">
                                <div class="btn-group mt-10">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" awPreviousStep>Back</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="TestPrint()"
                                        awNextStep>Continue</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </aw-wizard-step>
                    <!-- HEALTH ISSUES -->
                    <aw-wizard-step stepTitle="11">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h5>Does {{addCusForm.get('DOG_NAME').value}} have any Health issues</h5>
                                <hr>
                                <h6>{{addCusForm.get('DOG_NAME').value}} has ...</h6>
                                <!-- <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" list="health_issues" placeholder="Select Health Issue"/>
                                    <datalist id="health_issues" >
                                        <option *ngFor="let hi of HEALTH_ISSUES" (change)='addHI(hi)'>{{hi.name}}
                                        </option>
                                    </datalist>
                                </div> -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2"
                                        (change)="addHI($event.target.value)" formControlName="HI_INPUT">
                                        <option value="0" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                                        <option *ngFor="let hi of HEALTH_ISSUES" [value]="hi.HI_ID" [hidden]="!hi.shown">{{hi.name}}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                                    *ngFor="let p of addCusForm.get('HI_ARRAY')['controls']; let i = index" (click)="DeleteHI(p,i)">
                                    {{p.value.HI_NAME}} <span class="badge badge-light">X</span></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 centered-content">
                                <div class="btn-group mt-10">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" awPreviousStep>Back</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" awNextStep>Continue</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </aw-wizard-step>
                    <!-- TREATS TYPE -->
                    <aw-wizard-step stepTitle="12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h5>Does {{addCusForm.get('DOG_NAME').value}} get any treats or snacks</h5>
                                <hr>
                                <h6>{{addCusForm.get('DOG_NAME').value}}...</h6>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                    <input type="radio" formControlName="TREATS_TYPE_CODE" value="001"
                                        class="custom-control-input">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlValidation2">Doesn't have
                                        any</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                    <input type="radio" formControlName="TREATS_TYPE_CODE" value="002"
                                        class="custom-control-input">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlValidation2">Has some</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                    <input type="radio" formControlName="TREATS_TYPE_CODE" value="003"
                                        class="custom-control-input">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlValidation2">Has lots</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 centered-content">
                                <div class="btn-group mt-10">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" awPreviousStep>Back</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" awNextStep>Continue</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </aw-wizard-step>
                    <!-- POSTCODE -->
                    <aw-wizard-step stepTitle="13">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h5>Where should we deliver {{addCusForm.get('DOG_NAME').value}}'s food?</h5>
                                <hr>
                                <h6>{{addCusForm.get('DOG_NAME').value}} lives at...</h6>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Your postcode</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex: 1111 8888"
                                        formControlName="POSTCODE">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 centered-content">
                                <div class="btn-group mt-10">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" awPreviousStep>Back</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" awNextStep>Continue</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </aw-wizard-step>
                    <!-- OWNER NAME & EMAIL -->
                    <aw-wizard-step stepTitle="14">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h5>Pup parent details</h5>
                                <hr>
                                <h6>Your Name</h6>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mia Mcdoglover"
                                        formControlName="FULLNAME">
                                </div>
                                <h6 class="mt-3">Your Email</h6>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="hamster.john@gmail.com"
                                        formControlName="EMAIL">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 centered-content">
                                <div class="btn-group mt-10">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" awPreviousStep>Back</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="PrintAllInfo()"
                                        awNextStep>Continue</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </aw-wizard-step>

                    <aw-wizard-step stepTitle="Finished">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h5>Calculating Plan</h5>
                                <hr>
                                <h6>Sub title 1</h6>
                                <p><strong>@Title content 1!.. </strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
                                    printing
                                    <strong>@Content content 1 </strong> and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                                    the
                                    industry's
                                    standard dummy text.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 centered-content">
                                <div class="btn-group mt-10">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" awPreviousStep>Back</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" awResetWizard>Finished</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </aw-wizard-step>
                </aw-wizard>
            </form>
        </app-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  public addCusForm: FormGroup;
  Allergies_ref: FormArray;
  HI_ref: FormArray;
  nthchecked = false;
  selectedHI: any;
  extrabreed: boolean = false;

  ALLERGIES = [
    { name: 'Chicken', value: 'Chicken_ID', is_selected: false },
    { name: 'Lamb', value: 'Lamb_ID', is_selected: false },
    { name: 'Beef', value: 'Beef_ID', is_selected: false },
    { name: 'Turkey', value: 'Turkey_ID', is_selected: false },
    { name: 'Fish', value: 'Fish_ID', is_selected: false },
    { name: 'Pork', value: 'Pork_ID', is_selected: false }
  ];
  HEALTH_ISSUES = [
    { HI_ID: 'Diabetes_id', name: 'Diabetes', shown: true},
    { HI_ID: 'Pancreatis_id', name: 'Pancreatis', shown: true},
    { HI_ID: 'IBD_id', name: 'IBD', shown: true},
    { HI_ID: 'Kidney_id', name: 'Kidney', shown: true},
    { HI_ID: 'Cancer_id', name: 'Cancer', shown: true},
  ];
  BREEDS = [
    {
      BREED_ID: 1,
      BREED_NAME: 'Shepherd'
    },
    {
      BREED_ID: 2,
      BREED_NAME: 'Chihuaha'
    },
    {
      BREED_ID: 3,
      BREED_NAME: 'Bulldog'
    },
    {
      BREED_ID: 4,
      BREED_NAME: 'Labrador'
    },
    {
      BREED_ID: 5,
      BREED_NAME: 'Poodle'
    },
  ];
  BREEDS_2: any[];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addCusForm = this.fb.group({
      DOG_NAME: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      GENDER_CODE: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      IS_SPAYED_NEUTERED: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      IS_SPAYED: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      IS_NEUTERED: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      DOG_AGE_CATEGORY: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      DOG_AGE_YEARS: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      DOG_AGE_MONTHS: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      DOG_AGE_WEEKS: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      BREED_ID: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      BREED_ID_2: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      FOOD_TYPE_CODE: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      EATING_STYLE_CODE: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      BODY_TYPE_CODE: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      WEIGHT: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      ACTIVITY_LEVEL_CODE: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      //HEALTH_ISSUE: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      TREATS_TYPE_CODE: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      POSTCODE: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      FULLNAME: [, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      EMAIL: [, { validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email] }],
      ALLERGIES_ARRAY: this.fb.array(
        this.ALLERGIES.map(
          allergy => this.fb.group({
            ALLERGY_ID: [allergy.value],
            ALLERGY_NAME: [allergy.name],
            IS_SELECTED: [allergy.is_selected]
          })
        )
      ),
      HI_INPUT: ['0', { validators: [Validators.required] }],
      HI_ARRAY: this.fb.array([])

    });

    this.Allergies_ref = this.addCusForm.get('ALLERGIES_ARRAY') as FormArray;
    this.HI_ref = this.addCusForm.get('HI_ARRAY') as FormArray;
  }

  TestPrint() {
    console.log(this.addCusForm.value);
  }

  SpayedOrNeutered() {
    if (this.addCusForm.get('GENDER_CODE').value === '001') {
      this.addCusForm.controls['IS_SPAYED'].setValue(false);
      this.addCusForm.controls['IS_NEUTERED'].setValue(this.addCusForm.get('IS_SPAYED_NEUTERED').value);
    }
    else {
      this.addCusForm.controls['IS_NEUTERED'].setValue(false);
      this.addCusForm.controls['IS_SPAYED'].setValue(this.addCusForm.get('IS_SPAYED_NEUTERED').value);
    }    
  }

  AddBreed(){
    this.BREEDS_2 = this.BREEDS.filter(x => x.BREED_ID !== parseInt(this.addCusForm.get('BREED_ID').value));
    console.log(this.BREEDS_2);
    
    this.extrabreed = true;
  }

  unCheckAll() {
    this.nthchecked = true;
    var arr = new FormArray([]);
    this.ALLERGIES.forEach(allergy => {
      arr.push(this.fb.group({
        ALLERGY_ID: allergy.value,
        ALLERGY_NAME: allergy.name,
        IS_SELECTED: new FormControl(allergy.is_selected)
      }));
    }
    );
    this.addCusForm.controls['ALLERGIES_ARRAY'].setValue(arr.value);
    console.log(this.addCusForm.get('ALLERGIES_ARRAY'));
  }

  onAllergyChange() {
    let tempcheck = true;
    this.Allergies_ref.value.forEach(val => {
      if (val.IS_SELECTED)
        tempcheck = false;
    });
    this.nthchecked = tempcheck;
  }

  addHI(hi){
    let res = this.HEALTH_ISSUES.find((x,i) =>{
      if(x.HI_ID === hi){
        x.shown = false;
        return x;
      }
    });    
    this.HI_ref.push(this.fb.group(
      {
        HI_ID: res.HI_ID,
        HI_NAME: res.name
      }
    )); 
    this.addCusForm.get('HI_INPUT').setValue('0');
  }

  DeleteHI(p,i){
    this.HEALTH_ISSUES.find(x=> {
      if(x.HI_ID === p.value.HI_ID)
      x.shown= true;
    });    
    this.HI_ref.removeAt(i);
  }

  PrintAllInfo() { 
    console.log(this.addCusForm.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I ended up not using formBuilder. I created a class called DOG, and initialized an array of this class. OnInit I would add a DOG object to the array and whenever the user wishes to enter extra dogs I would push new objects as well. Each question had a *ngFor="let dog of DOGS" then the values were binded by using [(ngModel)]. I don't know if this was the only/best way to do so or if it's feasible with Reactive Forms but it did the trick.